# Exclude Registry Paths From User Profile Disk Roaming

Tags: office365, remote-desktop, windows-server-2019, terminal-services, terminal-services-gateway

We use UPD's in RDS environments (Server 2019)

Microsoft have recently announced guidance explaining we should be excluding the files at the bottom of this question, from roaming inside the UPD.

We can exclude files and folders in the RDS properties, but not the registry keys. We do need the registry to sync for lots of other apps but need to exclude just these hive paths.

Any ideas anyone?

%localappdata%\Packages\Microsoft.AAD.BrokerPlugin_cw5n1h2txyewy

%localappdata%\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.CloudExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy

%localappdata%\Packages<any app package>\AC\TokenBroker

%localappdata%\Microsoft\TokenBroker

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\IdentityCRL

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AAD

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\WorkplaceJoin

I tried to add the registry entries into the folder path.

[image]